# Fastest De-/Serialise struct in .Net

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I wrote this code to De- and serialise structures afap using IL generation (comments describes C# analogue). What can be improved here?

```
using System;
using System.Reflection;
using System.Reflection.Emit;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

namespace StructInterop
{
    public static class StructInterOp
    {
        static readonly ConstructorInfo IntPtrCtor = typeof(IntPtr).GetConstructor(new[] { typeof(void*) });
        static readonly MethodInfo MarshalCopy = typeof(Marshal).GetMethod("Copy", new[] { typeof(IntPtr), typeof(byte[]), typeof(int), typeof(int) });
        private static class DelegateHolder<T> where T : struct
        {
            // ReSharper disable MemberHidesStaticFromOuterClass
            // ReSharper disable StaticMemberInGenericType
            public static readonly Type TypeOfT = typeof(T);
            public static readonly int SizeInBytes = Marshal.SizeOf(TypeOfT);

            public static readonly Func<T, byte[]> Serialize = CreateSerializationDelegate();
            public static readonly Func<byte[], T> Deserialize = CreateDeserializationDelegate();


            //public static byte[] Serialize(T value)
            //{
            //    IntPtr p = new IntPtr(&value);
            //    byte[] result = new byte[sizeof(T)];
            //    Marshal.Copy(p, result, 0, result.Length);
            //    return result;
            //}
            private static Func<T, byte[]> CreateSerializationDelegate()
            {
                var dm = new DynamicMethod("Serialize" + TypeOfT.Name,
                    typeof(byte[]),
                    new[] { TypeOfT },
                    Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ManifestModule);
                dm.DefineParameter(1, ParameterAttributes.None, "value");

                var generator = dm.GetILGenerator();
                generator.DeclareLocal(typeof(byte[]));

                //IntPtr p = new IntPtr(&value);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarga_S, (byte)0);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_U);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, IntPtrCtor);

                //byte[] result = new byte[sizeof(T)]; 
                OpCode ldcStructSize = SizeInBytes < sbyte.MaxValue ? OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S : OpCodes.Ldc_I4;
                generator.Emit(ldcStructSize, SizeInBytes);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof(byte));

                //Marshal.Copy(p, result, 0, result.Length);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldlen);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_I4);
                generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, MarshalCopy, null);

                //return result
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);

                return (Func<T, byte[]>)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, byte[]>));
            }

            //public static T Deserialize(byte[] data)
            //{
            //    fixed (byte* pData = &data[0])
            //    {
            //        return *(T*)pData;
            //    }
            //}
            private static Func<byte[], T> CreateDeserializationDelegate()
            {
                var dm = new DynamicMethod("Deserialize" + TypeOfT.Name,
                                            TypeOfT,
                                            new[] { typeof(byte[]) },
                                            Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ManifestModule);
                dm.DefineParameter(1, ParameterAttributes.None, "data");
                var generator = dm.GetILGenerator();
                generator.DeclareLocal(typeof(byte).MakePointerType(), pinned: true);
                generator.DeclareLocal(TypeOfT);

                //fixed (byte* pData = &data[0])
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarg_0);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldelema, typeof(byte));
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);

                // return *(T*)pData;
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_I);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldobj, TypeOfT);
                generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
                return (Func<byte[], T>)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<byte[], T>));
            }
        }


        /// <summary>
        /// Do not check array bounds, possible buffer overflow
        /// </summary>
        public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] data) where T : struct
        {
            return DelegateHolder<T>.Deserialize(data);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Check array bounds
        /// </summary>
        public static T DeserializeSafe<T>(byte[] data) where T : struct
        {
            if (DelegateHolder<T>.SizeInBytes != data.Length)
                throw new ArgumentException(string.Format("Struct size is {0} bytes but array is {1} bytes length", DelegateHolder<T>.SizeInBytes, data.Length));
            return DelegateHolder<T>.Deserialize(data);
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Marshal struct in byte array without any type information
        /// </summary>
        public static byte[] Serialize<T>(this T value) where T : struct
        {
            return DelegateHolder<T>.Serialize(value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: But why the delegates? Their compilation is a huge (one time) overhead, and also the invocation has an additional cost comparable to a virtual method call. The fastest solution I could come up with is [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69722043/5114784).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Naming

`Interop` should be treated as a single word like in `System.Runtime.InteropServices`. You should also [not name a class the same as its namespace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/ericlippert/do-not-name-a-class-the-same-as-its-namespace-part-one). Which is why this is really not good:

```
namespace StructInterop
{
    public static class StructInterOp
    {
```

Given that the `StructInterOp` class has methods like `Serialize` and `Deserialize` - why not call it `StructSerializer`?

## Structure

You could remove a lot of your comments by spliting up the generation a bit. (The names for the new methods aren't great...)

```
//public static byte[] Serialize(T value)
//{
//    IntPtr p = new IntPtr(&value);
//    byte[] result = new byte[sizeof(T)];
//    Marshal.Copy(p, result, 0, result.Length);
//    return result;
//}
private static Func<T, byte[]> CreateSerializationDelegate()
{
    var dm = new DynamicMethod("Serialize" + TypeOfT.Name,
        typeof(byte[]),
        new[] { TypeOfT },
        Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().ManifestModule);
    dm.DefineParameter(1, ParameterAttributes.None, "value");

    var generator = dm.GetILGenerator();
    generator.DeclareLocal(typeof(byte[]));

    GenerateIntPtr(generator);
    GenerateResultArray(generator);
    GenerateCopy(generator);
    GenerateReturn(generator);

    return (Func<T, byte[]>)dm.CreateDelegate(typeof(Func<T, byte[]>));
}

private static void GenerateReturn(ILGenerator generator)
{
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ret);
}

private static void GenerateCopy(ILGenerator generator)
{
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Stloc_0);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldc_I4_0);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldloc_0);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldlen);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_I4);
    generator.EmitCall(OpCodes.Call, MarshalCopy, null);
}

private static void GenerateResultArray(ILGenerator generator)
{
    OpCode ldcStructSize = SizeInBytes < sbyte.MaxValue ? OpCodes.Ldc_I4_S : OpCodes.Ldc_I4;
    generator.Emit(ldcStructSize, SizeInBytes);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newarr, typeof(byte));
}

private static void GenerateIntPtr(ILGenerator generator)
{
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Ldarga_S, (byte)0);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Conv_U);
    generator.Emit(OpCodes.Newobj, IntPtrCtor);
}
```

## Comments

```
/// <summary>
/// Do not check array bounds, possible buffer overflow
/// </summary>
public static T Deserialize<T>(byte[] data) where T : struct
```

That's not a good comment. It should summarise what the method does:

```
/// <summary>
/// Deserializes the given data to the specified type.
/// </summary>
/// <paramref name="data">The serialized struct data.</paramref>
/// <typeparam name="T">The type of the struct to be deserialized.</typeparam>
/// <returns>An instance of type <typeparamref name="T"/></returns>
```

Comment: >> why not call it StructSerializer - I was assuming add more methods to interop with structs.
>> You could remove a lot of your comments by spliting up the generation a bit - I had same idea but I found comments makes code "cleaner", than method extract

Comment: @AlexZhukovskiy - Serializing structs is enough for one class to do. It's easy enough to create more classes for other things. Fair enough about the comments explaining the IL generation; it's very much personal preference there.